# Apartment gem: How to rename tenant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

Can we able to rename the tenant in **apartment-gem** or we have to drop the tenant and create a new one to achieve this.

Please provide me some suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is available through the apartment gem, but it is fairly simple to do with a SQL query. It depends on your setup though.

If you are using Postgresql with a schema for each tenant:

```
ALTER SCHEMA old RENAME TO new;
```

If you are using MySql, you should rename the table name prefixes for the tenant. This should work if the databases are on the same file system:

```
RENAME TABLE current_tenant.table TO new_tenant.table;
```

Disclaimer: not tested.

Answer (score 4):

You can change name (in my case subdomain) doing something like this:

1) Your schema should be some unique column in Tenant model (`schema_id` is fine). I am generating it's value from subdomain and Tenant ID.
2) In `apartment.rb` you `require "apartment/elevators/generic"`. Then

```
config.tenant_names = -> { Tenant.pluck :schema_id }
```

so you use schema stuff like tenant name.
Then on the bottom of the file add

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use "Apartment::Elevators::Generic", lambda { |request|
  Tenant.find_by(subdomain: request.host.split(".").first).schema_id
}
```

Now after you make proper subdomain requests stuff, you or your tenant user can edit name/subdomain and data in schemas will be safe.

PS: Also see here - https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/242